# How much space does QToolButton have for text?

Tags: c++, qt, qtoolbutton

I'm trying to subclass `QToolButton` to elide its text. To tell how much room is left for text, I have to take button width (available) and subtract from it:

1. icon size (available),
2. size of the button frame with shadows and other cute effects (**can't find it**),
3. padding (**can't find it either**).

Obviously these things are style-dependent and there must be API calls to retrieve them, but `QStyle` does not seem to offer anything relevant. Any suggestions?

Comment: I looked at the documentation. It looks like this is relevant: (http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/application-windows.html#window-geometry) But it says " For all child widgets, the frame geometry is equal to the widget's client geometry." which seems ungood.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf Can't see how this applies, sorry. I got a reasonably crazy two-pass idea in the meantime: create a button with text of known screen width, then subtract this known width from the resulting button width and assume it's the 'everything else' width. Meh.

Comment: We can just set the required size.  I do `pBn->setIcon(icn); pBn->setIconSize(icsz); pBn->setContnentMargins(1,1,1,1);` and then use `QFontMetrics` for evaluating text size which is not precise for its `boundingRect()` and I try to use own formula with it. After all sizes calculated and summed up `pBn->setFixedSize(bnWidth, bnHeight);`. Of course I cannot offer that as an answer yet because your question is how to get the size remaining for the text.